# error: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++

Heres my error...

"In constructor 'NumGame::NumGame(int&)':
error: no matching function for call to 'Category::Category()'"

Ive looked at a few similar questions here but cant seem to find an answer. I have a base class Category and NumGame is inherited from it but wont compile.

```
class Category {

public:
    void virtual selection(int&);
    Category(int&);
    virtual ~Category(){};
private:
    int myRandNum;
};

Category::Category(int& a){
    myRandNum = a;
}

void Category::selection(int& a){
    cout << "I am NumGame version number... " << a << endl;
    cout << "Now Im playing... " << myRandNum << endl;
}

class NumGame : public Category {

public:
    void selection(int&);
    NumGame(int&);
    ~NumGame(){};
private:
    int myRandNum;
};

NumGame::NumGame(int& b){
    myRandNum = b;
}

void NumGame::selection(int& b) {

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Category` does not have a default constructor, so you need to supply arguments when constructing the `Category` base object of `NumGame`:

```
NumGame::NumGame(int& b) :
    Category(b)
{
    myRandNum = b;
}
```

Comment: But am I not just over riding the default constructor anyway? And if I dont over ride it, then the default constructor will be used instead which is why I have arguments in the default one. BTW both answers have caused my code to compile, obviously some things are not clear to me :)

Answer (score 22):

**Reason for the error:**

When you create an instance of derived class `NumGame` the Base class `Category` no argument constructor is called to create the `Category`part of the object. Your class doesn't have one and the compiler complains about it.

**Why the compiler did not synthesize the default constructor?**

Once you provide any constructor for your class the compiler does not synthesize the constructor which does not take any argument for you, You have to provide that yourself if your code *uses* one.

**Solutions:**

There are two ways to avoid the error:

Call the appropriate available constructor in Base class `Catoegory` subobject through **[Member Initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor/8523361#8523361)**. This removes the scenario where your code *uses* a no argument constructor.

```
NumGame::NumGame(int& b) : Category(b)
{

}
```

**OR**

You need to provide a no argument constrcutor for `Category` class yourself:

```
Category::Category()
{

}
```

Comment: Great, the only answer on SO that helped me to fix this. :D

Answer (score 0):

in your `NumGame` class you have to provide a call to constructor of base class. if you don t, compiler do it for you with default contructor : in your case `Category()` that you don t have..