# No matching function for call in constructor - C++ 11

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, c++11, constructor

I am trying to create two classes: One for a Card, which holds two strings of rank and suit, and the other class for Hand, which holds an array of size 5 of Card objects.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Card
{

    public:
    explicit Card(string rank, string suit){
        this->rank = rank;
        this->suit = suit;
    }

    string getRank(){
        return rank;
    }

    string getSuit(){
        return suit;
    }

    protected:
    string rank;
    string suit;

}; 

class Hand
{
    public:
    explicit Hand(Card cards[5]){
        this->cards[5] = cards[5];
    }

    protected:
    Card cards[5];
    bool isFlush;
    bool isStraight;
    bool isRoyal;
    bool isPair;
    bool istwoPair;
    bool isTOAK;
    bool isFOAK;
};
```

When trying to compile, I get:

```
wip.cpp:33:35: error: no matching function for call to 'Card::Card()'
   33 |     explicit Hand(Card myCards[5]){
      |                                   ^
```

Why is the constructor getting an error? I understand the message of `No matching function for call to Card::Card()`, but I don't plan on instantiating this blankly. I will be creating five cards, then assigning five cards to a class. Something like:

```
int main(){
    Card card1("3", "Spade");
    Card card2("3", "Spade");
    Card card3("A", "Diamond");
    Card card4("K", "Heart");    
    Card card5("1", "Spade");

    Card hand1cards[5] {card1, card2, card3, card4, card5};

    Hand myHand(hand1cards);    

}
```

So I don't plan on having to do constructor overloading, so why am I getting this error? What can I do to fix my constructor to allow me to pass in a fixed-size array of Card objects to create a Hand object?

I have looked at a few other questions with similar problems, namely:

[How do you use the non-default constructor for a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088944/how-do-you-use-the-non-default-constructor-for-a-member)

[error: no matching function for call to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682548/error-no-matching-function-for-call-to)

["error: no matching function for call to"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326260/error-no-matching-function-for-call-to)

Yet none of them seem to deal with my problem (passing array of another class to this class).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use the non-default constructor for a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088944/how-do-you-use-the-non-default-constructor-for-a-member)

Comment: Also be aware that [arrays are not passed by value to functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309136/passing-arrays-to-function-in-c), `Cards card[5]` is the same as `Cards* card`. You should probably use an `std::array` instead, which works as you intend it to.

Comment: `this->cards[5] = ...` writes to an array element that does not exist. The valid indices of `cards` are 0 to 4.

Comment: I know the indices 0->4 since array is 0-based, not like MATLAB, but I was trying to say of size 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ has [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) that you included but didn't use.
You can change the constructor to this:

```
explicit Hand(array<Card, 5> cards) : cards(cards){}
```

Live on [`godbolt`](https://godbolt.org/z/dcIQXH)

---

This is wrong:

```
this->cards[5] = cards[5];
```

It is accessing 6th element of `cards`, which is not there and causes an [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: This is what I was intending. I forgot differencei n C++ between archaic array and `std::array`

Comment: @JerryM. I thought you mistook it with C array too.